# How to write shorter an event for a delegated selector and a direct selector?

Tags: jquery, events, event-listener

Is there a better and cleaner way and to write these jQuery events ?

```
$(".class").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    functionTest();
});

$("#selector").on("click", ".class", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    functionTest();

});
```

I was thinking about something like the following, but I understand that it's definitely not the appropriate way:

```
$("#selector, .class").on("click", ".class", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    functionTest();

});
```

Regarding the html structure, I have:

```
<div>
<a href="" class=".class">button</a>
</div>

<div id="#selector">
<!-- Dynamically generated html -->
<a href="" class=".class" id="id1">button</a>
<a href="" class=".class" id="id2">button</a>
<a href="" class=".class" id="id3">button</a>
<!-- Dynamically generated html -->
</div>
```

Comment: So long as all the `.class` elements are children of the `#selector` element, then you can use the delegated event handler alone.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan indeed, but I do not have descendant selectors only of `.class`

Comment: In that case your first example is the only way to achieve what you require, short of delegating the `click` handler to the `document`, but that's not a great idea.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, but in this case, my dynamically generated code having `.class` is not fired on click (loaded with ajax), descendant of `#selector`

Comment: That's why you need the delegated event handler...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hahaha sorry, I may not have been clear enough, give me a second so I show my `html`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Maybe I cannot shorten this code ???

Comment: Not really, as I mentioned before you need to use two separate handlers as the target elements are not descendants. You could use a single delegated handler from `$(document).on(...` but that may cause unforeseen issues.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok thanks !. Can you write it as answer so I can close the question ?

Comment: I added it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the `.class` elements are child elements of `#selector`, then you can use a single delegated event handler:

```
$("#selector").on("click", ".class", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  functionTest();
});
```

If this is not the case then you could need to use two separate event handlers, as in your first example.